# Does a sudden ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID maybe suggest a man-in-the-middle attack?

Tags: network

For months I regularly visited *Russia Today* ([www.rt.com](http://www.rt.com)) with no problem. Then:

- 4 days ago, without even closing my Chrome browser on MacOS, www.rt.com just stopped loading.
- on the command line, www.rt.com resolves to 207.244.80.166.
- typing 207.244.80.166 into Chrome loads this error message:

  > Error: "Subject Alternative Name Missing" or NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID or "Your connection is not private"
- a traceroute makes it to 207.244.80.166 in 11 hops.
- typing www.rt.com into a Chrome browser on Windows XP loads with no problems.
- Chrome browser on iPhone using the local WiFi does **not** load.
- Chrome browser on iPhone using a cellular network loads ok.

There is a public effort to restrict access to Russia Today from inside USA on youtube as well as www.rt.com. Am I being affected by this? What is that error?

Comment: Possible, but we can't give you a clear yes/no with this informations. Other possibilities include errors by the rt admins, bugs in Chrome, bugs and/or malicious code in other programs you've installed (Windows, antivirus, ...), malicious programs you didn't want to have in general, etc.etc.

Comment: But something to think about: What would the US government gain by doing MITM without a correct certificate (they could certainly get one that is  accepted by your browser), between a single random person and rt.com specifically? In their position, I would a) get good certificates, and b) don't try to intercept user traffic of a public news site, but eg. put my own real-looking "news" there. At least if I really had to do something with rt.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> typing 207.244.80.166 into Chrome loads this error message:
>   Error: "Subject Alternative Name Missing" or NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID or "Your connection is not private"

This is the expected  behavior. If you specify the IP address instead of the hostname in the URL it will expect that the site returns a certificate which matches this IP address. But, the certificate returned for this site is not for a specific IP address but only for a hostname, i.e. it covers rt.com and *.rt.com.

"Subject Alternative Name Missing" is slightly misleading since the certificate actually has subject alternative names (SAN). Only, it has no SAN for an IP address but this is expected since you've entered an IP address in the URL.

> Gosh, could this mysterious error message that just came out of nowhere be explained by a man-in-the-middle attack?

There does not need to be any man-in-the-middle attack involved to get this kind of error. You get the same problems with other sites when just using the IP address in the URL instead of the hostname. Try for example `https://104.102.5.46/` which uses the IP address for `www.whitehouse.gov` and you'll see that the problem is the same.

Comment: sorry. sorry. I should have checked that.